# Pass list as a parameter to function and iterate through in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am a newbie in groovy thus it might be a broad question but any help will be appreciated. I have to pass each index in the keys Set to the `createFixVersion` as an argument but could find how should I do this.

The main thing is that I am trying to do is, I have to create a fixversion for each of projects in the keys list where currently prepared for hardcoded and only for a single project. How can I do this?

```
     def keys = [CMPNT, DBCCO, OPP]

     def fixVersionFromJira = jira.createFixVersion([
       name: fixVersionName,
       project: keys, --> not sure this is correct
       released: false
      ])
      println fixVersionFromJira


      public def createFixVersion(Map args) {
        if(!config.jira.projectKey) {
          throw new Exception("'jira.projectKey' not set in library configuration!")
        }
    
        def defaultArgs = [
          name: '',
          project: config.jira.projectKey,
          archived: false,
          released: true
        ]
    
        def payloadArgs = defaultArgs + args
    
        arguments.checkRequired(payloadArgs, defaultArgs.keySet().collect())
    
        def payload = [
          name: payloadArgs.name,
          description: payloadArgs.description ? payloadArgs.description : '',
          userReleaseDate: payloadArgs.userReleaseDate ? payloadArgs.userReleaseDate : '',
          project: payloadArgs.project,
          archived: payloadArgs.archived,
          released: payloadArgs.released,
        ]
    
        def json = JsonOutput.toJson(payload)
    
        return 

post([data: json, api: "version/"])
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking for this `keys.each { key ->  createFixVersion(key) }` ?

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka' partially yes but meantime I have to pass another param likewise the questions. I mean name and released. So actually i need two things. 1. Refactor createFixVersion function according to the list
2.Change the way of calling function

Comment: Each index in the keyset.. so `keys.keySet().each { key ->  createFixVersion(key) }` ?

Comment: ok but how can I pass the rest of the parameters when calling `createFixVersion(key)`.. And what should I change to `createFixVersion` function

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, I've got the full context, but I see you want to apply some workflow for multiple projects data, so here I tried to show how it might be implemented.

But it's highly likely this code should be adjusted with understanding all the details of your context.

```
def projects = [
        [
                key           : 'CMPNT',
                fixVersionName: '1',
                released      : false
        ],
        [
                key           : 'DBCCO',
                fixVersionName: '1.1',
                released      : false
        ],
        [
                key           : 'OPP',
                fixVersionName: '1.2',
                released      : false
        ],
]

projects.each { project ->
    project.fixVersionFromJira = jira.createFixVersion([
            name    : project.fixVersionName,
            project : project.key,
            released: project.released
    ])
}

projects.each { project ->
    createFixVersion(project)
}

public def createFixVersion(Map project) {
    if (!project.key) {
        throw new Exception("'jira.projectKey' not set in library configuration!")
    }

    def defaultArgs = [
            name    : project.fixVersionFromJira,
            project : project.key,
            archived: false,
            released: project.released
    ]

    def payloadArgs = defaultArgs + args

    arguments.checkRequired(payloadArgs, defaultArgs.keySet().collect())

    def payload = [
            name           : payloadArgs.name,
            description    : payloadArgs.description ? payloadArgs.description : '',
            userReleaseDate: payloadArgs.userReleaseDate ? payloadArgs.userReleaseDate : '',
            project        : payloadArgs.project,
            archived       : payloadArgs.archived,
            released       : payloadArgs.released,
    ]

    def json = JsonOutput.toJson(payload)

    post([data: json, api: "version/"])
}
```